# Is there a downside for running docker experimental features?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-engine

I know that Docker allows enabling experimental features on the daemon side in a rather simple way:

Add/update `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```sh
{
"experimental": true
}
```

And enabling experimental features brings a couple of cool things (e.g. Metrics (Prometheus) output for basic container, image, and daemon operations) and provide early access to future product functionality.

My question is what are exactly the dangers of enabling experimental features? Because they're not enable by default and I assume they are not ok for production environments as Docker doesn't offer support for experimental features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The experimental features, are features which are being tested by Docker, and the issues with this would be worked on, for a next mainstream release of a Docker Engine version. the risk is Docker may not add these experimental features, into a future mainstream release, of a Docker engine version.

Comment: Thx. Shaqil, I was wondering if there are any issue from security perspective also, because I've been searching and couldn't find anything conclusive regarding this subject .